How to make a multiple match into an aggregate comparing the full string on MongoDB?
I'm trying to make a $and clause within a $match clause. This $and clause should have a full complete comparison against the string I'm providing. I'd like to make sure that the comparisong with attributes.value should be exact the string I'm passing. With the following expression:
db.getCollection('cards').aggregate([
    {
        "$match": {
            'attributes.key': 'setCode',
            'attributes.value': 'qc'
        }
    },
    {
        "$match": {
            'attributes.key': 'code',
            'attributes.value': 'potions'
        }
    }]);

Some sample data that is returned with the query above:
[
  {
    "_id": {"$oid": "66ab6eec2982eff57de4423a"},
    "attributes": [
      {
        "key": "name",
        "displayText": "",
        "value": "Weakness Potion",
        "values": [],
        "searchable": true,
        "visible": true,
        "language": ""
      },
      {
        "key": "code",
        "displayText": "",
        "value": "weakness-potion",
        "values": [],
        "searchable": true,
        "visible": true,
        "language": ""
      },
      {
        "key": "text",
        "displayText": "",
        "value": "To play this card, discard 1 of your Potions Lessons from play. Do 5 damage to your opponent. During your opponent's next turn, prevent all damage done to you by your opponent's Creatures.",
        "values": [],
        "searchable": true,
        "visible": true,
        "language": ""
      },
      {
        "key": "illustrator",
        "displayText": "",
        "value": "Keith Garletts",
        "values": [],
        "searchable": true,
        "visible": true,
        "language": ""
      },
      {
        "key": "orientation",
        "displayText": "",
        "value": "vertical",
        "values": [],
        "searchable": true,
        "visible": true,
        "language": ""
      },
      {
        "key": "set",
        "displayText": "",
        "value": "Quidditch Cup",
        "values": [],
        "searchable": true,
        "visible": true,
        "language": ""
      },
      {
        "key": "setCode",
        "displayText": "",
        "value": "qc",
        "values": [],
        "searchable": true,
        "visible": false,
        "language": ""
      },
      {
        "key": "type",
        "displayText": "",
        "value": "Spell",
        "values": [],
        "searchable": true,
        "visible": true,
        "language": ""
      },
      {
        "key": "typeCode",
        "displayText": "",
        "value": "spell",
        "values": [],
        "searchable": true,
        "visible": true,
        "language": ""
      },
      {
        "key": "rarity",
        "displayText": "",
        "value": "Uncommon",
        "values": [],
        "searchable": true,
        "visible": true,
        "language": ""
      },
      {
        "key": "rarityCode",
        "displayText": "",
        "value": "uncommon",
        "values": [],
        "searchable": true,
        "visible": true,
        "language": ""
      },
      {
        "key": "lessonType",
        "displayText": "",
        "value": "Potions",
        "values": [],
        "searchable": true,
        "visible": true,
        "language": ""
      },
      {
        "key": "lessonTypeCode",
        "displayText": "",
        "value": "potions",
        "values": [],
        "searchable": true,
        "visible": true,
        "language": ""
      },
      {
        "key": "lessonCost",
        "displayText": "",
        "value": "7",
        "values": [],
        "searchable": true,
        "visible": true,
        "language": ""
      },
      {
        "key": "actionCost",
        "displayText": "",
        "value": "1",
        "values": [],
        "searchable": true,
        "visible": true,
        "language": ""
      },
      {
        "key": "cardNumber",
        "displayText": "",
        "value": "50",
        "values": [],
        "searchable": true,
        "visible": true,
        "language": ""
      },
      {
        "key": "subType",
        "displayText": "",
        "value": "",
        "values": [],
        "searchable": true,
        "visible": true,
        "language": ""
      }
    ],
    "language": "en"
  },
  {
    "_id": {"$oid": "66ab6eec2982eff57de4423d"},
    "attributes": [
      {
        "key": "name",
        "displayText": "",
        "value": "Bruisewort Balm",
        "values": [],
        "searchable": true,
        "visible": true,
        "language": ""
      },
      {
        "key": "code",
        "displayText": "",
        "value": "bruisewort-balm",
        "values": [],
        "searchable": true,
        "visible": true,
        "language": ""
      },
      {
        "key": "text",
        "displayText": "",
        "value": "Shuffle up to 5 non-Healing cards from your discard pile into your deck.",
        "values": [],
        "searchable": true,
        "visible": true,
        "language": ""
      },
      {
        "key": "illustrator",
        "displayText": "",
        "value": "Alex Horley",
        "values": [],
        "searchable": true,
        "visible": true,
        "language": ""
      },
      {
        "key": "orientation",
        "displayText": "",
        "value": "vertical",
        "values": [],
        "searchable": true,
        "visible": true,
        "language": ""
      },
      {
        "key": "set",
        "displayText": "",
        "value": "Quidditch Cup",
        "values": [],
        "searchable": true,
        "visible": true,
        "language": ""
      },
      {
        "key": "setCode",
        "displayText": "",
        "value": "qc",
        "values": [],
        "searchable": true,
        "visible": false,
        "language": ""
      },
      {
        "key": "type",
        "displayText": "",
        "value": "Spell",
        "values": [],
        "searchable": true,
        "visible": true,
        "language": ""
      },
      {
        "key": "typeCode",
        "displayText": "",
        "value": "spell",
        "values": [],
        "searchable": true,
        "visible": true,
        "language": ""
      },
      {
        "key": "rarity",
        "displayText": "",
        "value": "Common",
        "values": [],
        "searchable": true,
        "visible": true,
        "language": ""
      },
      {
        "key": "rarityCode",
        "displayText": "",
        "value": "common",
        "values": [],
        "searchable": true,
        "visible": true,
        "language": ""
      },
      {
        "key": "lessonType",
        "displayText": "",
        "value": "Potions",
        "values": [],
        "searchable": true,
        "visible": true,
        "language": ""
      },
      {
        "key": "lessonTypeCode",
        "displayText": "",
        "value": "potions",
        "values": [],
        "searchable": true,
        "visible": true,
        "language": ""
      },
      {
        "key": "lessonCost",
        "displayText": "",
        "value": "3",
        "values": [],
        "searchable": true,
        "visible": true,
        "language": ""
      },
      {
        "key": "actionCost",
        "displayText": "",
        "value": "1",
        "values": [],
        "searchable": true,
        "visible": true,
        "language": ""
      },
      {
        "key": "cardNumber",
        "displayText": "",
        "value": "53",
        "values": [],
        "searchable": true,
        "visible": true,
        "language": ""
      },
      {
        "key": "subType",
        "displayText": "",
        "value": "",
        "values": ["Healing"],
        "searchable": true,
        "visible": true,
        "language": ""
      }
    ],
    "language": "en"
  },
  {
    "_id": {"$oid": "66ab6eec2982eff57de44256"},
    "attributes": [
      {
        "key": "name",
        "displayText": "",
        "value": "Potions",
        "values": [],
        "searchable": true,
        "visible": true,
        "language": ""
      },
      {
        "key": "code",
        "displayText": "",
        "value": "potions",
        "values": [],
        "searchable": true,
        "visible": true,
        "language": ""
      },
      {
        "key": "text",
        "displayText": "",
        "value": "Provides 1 Potions lesson.",
        "values": [],
        "searchable": true,
        "visible": true,
        "language": ""
      },
      {
        "key": "illustrator",
        "displayText": "",
        "value": "Shanth Enjeti, Melissa Ferreira",
        "values": [],
        "searchable": true,
        "visible": true,
        "language": ""
      },
      {
        "key": "orientation",
        "displayText": "",
        "value": "horizontal",
        "values": [],
        "searchable": true,
        "visible": true,
        "language": ""
      },
      {
        "key": "set",
        "displayText": "",
        "value": "Quidditch Cup",
        "values": [],
        "searchable": true,
        "visible": true,
        "language": ""
      },
      {
        "key": "setCode",
        "displayText": "",
        "value": "qc",
        "values": [],
        "searchable": true,
        "visible": false,
        "language": ""
      },
      {
        "key": "type",
        "displayText": "",
        "value": "Lesson",
        "values": [],
        "searchable": true,
        "visible": true,
        "language": ""
      },
      {
        "key": "typeCode",
        "displayText": "",
        "value": "lesson",
        "values": [],
        "searchable": true,
        "visible": true,
        "language": ""
      },
      {
        "key": "rarity",
        "displayText": "",
        "value": "Common",
        "values": [],
        "searchable": true,
        "visible": true,
        "language": ""
      },
      {
        "key": "rarityCode",
        "displayText": "",
        "value": "common",
        "values": [],
        "searchable": true,
        "visible": true,
        "language": ""
      },
      {
        "key": "lessonType",
        "displayText": "",
        "value": "Potions",
        "values": [],
        "searchable": true,
        "visible": true,
        "language": ""
      },
      {
        "key": "lessonTypeCode",
        "displayText": "",
        "value": "potions",
        "values": [],
        "searchable": true,
        "visible": true,
        "language": ""
      },
      {
        "key": "actionCost",
        "displayText": "",
        "value": "1",
        "values": [],
        "searchable": true,
        "visible": true,
        "language": ""
      },
      {
        "key": "cardNumber",
        "displayText": "",
        "value": "78",
        "values": [],
        "searchable": true,
        "visible": true,
        "language": ""
      },
      {
        "key": "providesLesson",
        "displayText": "",
        "value": "Potions",
        "values": [],
        "searchable": true,
        "visible": true,
        "language": ""
      },
      {
        "key": "subType",
        "displayText": "",
        "value": "",
        "values": [],
        "searchable": true,
        "visible": true,
        "language": ""
      }
    ],
    "language": "en"
  }
]

As you can see, I get results that match with the code like potion, potions, cauldron potion. I'm also getting results where other attributes with different keys, have the word potions within.
So my $match clause is not respecting the attributes.key with values setCode and code, because it's comparing with other attributes.
How can I make sure that the above $match condition matches only the given keys and given values?
Thank you all!

Provide some example data. You'll probably need to use $elemMatch with attributes, otherwise any combination of those .key & .value fields with that text will match.

Thanks @aneroid, added some result samples for further checking. How you think the elemMatch would work with that dataset?

For your current example data, use $elemMatch with $all:
db.cards.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "attributes": {
        $all: [
          { $elemMatch: { "key": "setCode", "value": "qc" } },
          { $elemMatch: { "key": "code", "value": "potions" } }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])

Mongo Playground
And this also works with find:
db.cards.find({
  "attributes": {
    $all: [
      { $elemMatch: { "key": "setCode", "value": "qc" } },
      { $elemMatch: { "key": "code", "value": "potions" } }
    ]
  }
})

Mongo Playground with find

Added a separate answer for the new example data.
Answer for previous example data:
Since attributes is an object and not an array of key-value fields, you don't need to do attr.key & attr.value. (And you also wouldn't need $elemMatch for your example data.)
Use the keys & values directly in the match:
db.getCollection('cards').aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "attributes.setCode": "qc",
      "attributes.code": "potions"
    }
  }
])

Mongo Playground
And unless you need an aggregation pipeline for some other steps, this can be used directly in a find query:
db.cards.find({
  "attributes.setCode": "qc",
  "attributes.code": "potions"
})

Mongo Playground

I actually added a proper sample: the previous one was with a projection result in it, sorry about that. It is an array at the end. With the elemMatch, I was able to achieve the results. Take a look at my answer below =)

Added a separate answer for the new example data. This was getting unreadable.

It is possible to achieve the results I want by following @aneroid's  suggestion with $elemMatch:
db.getCollection('cards').aggregate([{
  "$match": {
    "attributes": {
      $elemMatch: {
        key: "setCode",
        value: "qc"
      }
    }
  }
}, {
  "$match": {
    "attributes": {
      $elemMatch: {
        key: "code",
        value: "potions"
      }
    }
  }
}]);

If anyone knows a better way for achieving the same result with a simpler query, let me know!

As @aneroid has already pointed out, there is no need to use $elemMatch. The 2nd option in his answer should be the "simpler query" you are looking for.
